# Embed Windows Explorer inside an MS Access form

Tags: ms-access, widget, explorer, windows-explorer

Is there a widget to embed an explorer-like view inside an ms access form?

I have a folder with the name of the primary key, which holds documents (.doc, .xls) for that dataset (it’s an employees table)

Currently I have a button which opens an explorer window, but having it embedded would be really nice.

Any help, link, similar question, and even a ›no, there isn’t‹ answer is highly appreciated

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OLE object Microsoft Web Browser on a form. Since Internet Explorer is capable of viewing files on your computer other than web pages.

Example Code: `WebBrowser0.Navigate2 ("C:\")`  would go to this Folder

Edit: per @hans use either Navigate2 or the alternate systax (file//:...).

Comment: Er, Internet Explorer != Explorer.

Comment: My Internet Explorer is capable of accessing files on my hard drive just like Explorer.

Comment: XP and before had this feature, but they really got rid of that.

Comment: We're still running XP at the office. Didn't try it at home.

Comment: WebBrowser0.Navigate works for me with Access 2007 on Windows 7 RTM.  However, I couldn't make WebBrowser0.Navigate accept "C:\" as its target.  (I had to use "file:///C:/")  But the Navigate2 method accepted the target as you described: WebBrowser0.Navigate2 "C:\"

Comment: thanks, i got it to work this way. i had to use browser0.object.navigate though